# Install Java 6 to Debian Lenny

Tags: debian, software-installation, java

I'm trying to install old Java 6 to Debian Lenny:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-jre sun-java6-bin
```

Got this error:

```
Couldn't find package  sun-java6-jdk
```

sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free     
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ lenny/updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 2):

Run `apt-cache search sun-java6-jdk` and you should see the exact package name you'll need to specify.

And your error message looks a little fishy:

```
Coudn't find package  sun-java6-jdk
```

If there really are two space characters after the word "package", it might mean you've accidentally typed Alt-Space or some other invisible character into the beginning of the package name. That might explain the issue. If that's the case, you'll need to type the command again: a version recalled from the command history will just have the same problem again.

Comment: The package list of the archive repository can be viewed using a web browser: http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/pool/non-free/s/sun-java6/ has the packages named like `sun-java6*`, and there is a package for Lenny. However, the version number may or may not be designated as part of the official package name, so that's why I asked to try `apt-cache search sun-java6-jdk` first.